Concurrency issue with DuckDB JDBC connector
I got a webservice extracting data from a DuckDB database and i'm experimenting exponential  response time from the SQL query execution as the number of simultaneous client increase.
I'm using the latest version of the DuckDB java connector (currently 1.1.2)
i made a very simple test case, showing the issue:
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String databaseUrl = "jdbc:duckdb:/home/glegal/Téléchargements/test-parquet/argo-v1.db";
        
        // some basic SQL query on a single table
        String query = """
                        SELECT m."z_value", m."time" , m."obsprop_id", m."result"  
                        FROM "main"."flat_csv_data" m 
                        WHERE "thing_id" like '1900022%' 
                        AND ( (m."time">='2003-05-07 14:50:35.0') OR (  m."time" <='2003-05-07 15:50:35.0' )) 
                       """;
    
         int nbThread = 1;
         
        Properties ro_prop = new Properties();
        ro_prop.setProperty("duckdb.read_only", "true");
        ro_prop.setProperty("access_mode", "READ_ONLY"); // i try to put this but it seems to have no effect
        
        // create an hikari datasource with maxPoolSize = nbThread
        DataSource ds = getDataSource(databaseUrl, nbThread, ro_prop, true);
        
        // create X thread that execute the query and read the response, then print the execution time
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbThread; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            Thread t = new Thread("Th-" + i) {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
                        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
                       
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            // read the results
                            rs.getInt(1);
                            rs.getTimestamp(2);
                            rs.getString(3);
                            rs.getDouble(4);
                        }
                        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                        System.out.println(this.getName() + " Execution time:" + humanReadableMilis(duration));
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            threads.add(t);
        }
        
        // launch all the threads and wait for completion
        for (Thread t :threads) t.start();
        
        boolean running = true;
        while (running) {
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            running = false;
            for (Thread t :threads) {
                if (t.isAlive()) running = true;
            }
            
        }
    }

I got the following results:
with 1 concurrent thread:
Th-0 Execution time:00 min, 01 sec

with 5 threads:
Th-4 Execution time:00 min, 03 sec
Th-0 Execution time:00 min, 03 sec
Th-1 Execution time:00 min, 05 sec
Th-3 Execution time:00 min, 05 sec
Th-2 Execution time:00 min, 05 sec

with 10 threads:
Th-9 Execution time:00 min, 06 sec
Th-0 Execution time:00 min, 06 sec
Th-8 Execution time:00 min, 08 sec
Th-2 Execution time:00 min, 08 sec
Th-7 Execution time:00 min, 09 sec
Th-6 Execution time:00 min, 09 sec
Th-5 Execution time:00 min, 10 sec
Th-1 Execution time:00 min, 10 sec
Th-3 Execution time:00 min, 11 sec
Th-4 Execution time:00 min, 11 sec

Am i configuring my DuckDB datasource wrong?
From what i understand, DuckDB should handle multi-thread when in read-only mode.
Is the problem come from the Java connector?
All the time seems to be spent in executeQery:
Th-1 connection aquire time:00 min, 00 sec, 32 ms
Th-1 execute query time:00 min, 11 sec, 748 ms
Th-1 read result time:00 min, 00 sec, 18 ms

Th-1 Execution time:00 min, 11 sec, 800 ms

here are the printed configuration result of the query
SELECT * FROM duckdb_settings()
results:
access_mode : read_only
allow_persistent_secrets : true
catalog_error_max_schemas : 100
checkpoint_threshold : 16.0 MiB
debug_checkpoint_abort : none
debug_skip_checkpoint_on_commit : false
storage_compatibility_version : v0.10.2
debug_force_external : false
debug_force_no_cross_product : false
debug_asof_iejoin : false
prefer_range_joins : false
debug_window_mode : NULL
default_collation : 
default_order : asc
default_null_order : nulls_last
disabled_filesystems : 
disabled_optimizers : 
enable_external_access : true
enable_fsst_vectors : false
allow_unsigned_extensions : false
allow_community_extensions : true
allow_extensions_metadata_mismatch : false
allow_unredacted_secrets : false
custom_extension_repository : 
autoinstall_extension_repository : 
autoinstall_known_extensions : true
autoload_known_extensions : true
enable_object_cache : false
enable_http_metadata_cache : false
enable_profiling : NULL
enable_progress_bar : false
enable_progress_bar_print : true
errors_as_json : false
explain_output : physical_only
extension_directory : 
external_threads : 1
file_search_path : 
force_compression : Auto
force_bitpacking_mode : auto
home_directory : 
http_proxy : 
http_proxy_username : 
http_proxy_password : 
log_query_path : NULL
enable_macro_dependencies : false
enable_view_dependencies : false
lock_configuration : false
ieee_floating_point_ops : true
immediate_transaction_mode : false
integer_division : false
max_expression_depth : 1000
streaming_buffer_size : 976.5 KiB
max_memory : 24.9 GiB
max_temp_directory_size : 0 bytes
max_vacuum_tasks : 100
merge_join_threshold : 1000
nested_loop_join_threshold : 5
old_implicit_casting : false
memory_limit : 24.9 GiB
null_order : nulls_last
order_by_non_integer_literal : false
ordered_aggregate_threshold : 262144
password : NULL
perfect_ht_threshold : 12
pivot_filter_threshold : 20
pivot_limit : 100000
preserve_identifier_case : true
preserve_insertion_order : true
profile_output : 
profiling_mode : NULL
profiling_output : 
custom_profiling_settings : {"ROWS_RETURNED": "true", "LATENCY": "true", "RESULT_SET_SIZE": "true", "OPERATOR_TIMING": "true", "OPERATOR_ROWS_SCANNED": "true", "CUMULATIVE_ROWS_SCANNED": "true", "OPERATOR_CARDINALITY": "true", "OPERATOR_TYPE": "true", "CUMULATIVE_CARDINALITY": "true", "EXTRA_INFO": "true", "CPU_TIME": "true", "BLOCKED_THREAD_TIME": "true", "QUERY_NAME": "true"}
progress_bar_time : 2000
schema : main
search_path : 
scalar_subquery_error_on_multiple_rows : true
secret_directory : /home/glegal/.duckdb/stored_secrets
default_secret_storage : local_file
temp_directory : /home/glegal/Téléchargements/test-parquet/argo-v1.db.tmp
threads : 16
username : NULL
arrow_large_buffer_size : false
arrow_output_list_view : false
arrow_lossless_conversion : false
produce_arrow_string_view : false
user : NULL
wal_autocheckpoint : 16.0 MiB
worker_threads : 16
allocator_flush_threshold : 128.0 MiB
allocator_bulk_deallocation_flush_threshold : 512.0 MiB
allocator_background_threads : false
duckdb_api : jdbc
custom_user_agent : 
partitioned_write_flush_threshold : 524288
partitioned_write_max_open_files : 100
default_block_size : 262144
index_scan_percentage : 0.001
index_scan_max_count : 2048
enable_http_logging : false
http_logging_output : 
enable_geoparquet_conversion : true
binary_as_string : 
Calendar : gregorian
TimeZone : Europe/Paris

the thread parameter is set on the number of my computer cores: 16.
yourkit profiling:


Have you tried to break down where the time is being lost?  I'd be tempted to log timestamps for each line in Thread.run, to see what's taking the time as starting point.

i print time for acquire connection, execute query, read results, almost all the time is spend in executeQuery.

It's a guess but I'd look at DuckDB itself; time being lost in the queries suggests, the engine isn't running those queries in parallel.  There seems to be many configuration options (https://duckdb.org/docs/configuration/overview), one of which is the number threads, that should be defaulting to the number of cores on your machine, but I check what values are being used.

looks like the number of threads is correctly set to 16

external_threads doesn't look good for your use-case, although again that's a guess.  The docs aren't immediately clear what an 'external task' is.

i had spotted this one. but after testing, increasing it does affect much the results. unless i set it to 16 (number of my computer core) and then the perf are even worse

Hmmm, I think you'll need to attach VisualVM or similar to watch the JMV while it runs and see if that sheds any light on it.

i'm affraid that is not helping. i'm using yourkit and it does not go down more than:
org.duckdb.DuckDBNative.duckdb_jdbc_execute(ByteBuffer, Object[])

Have you tried running your test with DuckDB in-memory?  Apparently using a connection string of jdbc:duckdb: will do this.

this will not help in my case, because i need to request an existing database in a large file.
